# I'm friendly with sin

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I can scare many people, I'm quite friendly with sin
In fact, he and I are practically twins
I'm the opposite of dry, if you'll pardon my French
Want a loan? You might need my help

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you...

> cosine

I can scare many people, I'm quite friendly with sin
In fact, he and I are practically twins

> Referencing how math can scare people, and sin/cosine

I'm the opposite of dry, if you'll pardon my French

> Referring to **sec**, the French word for dry. (Thanks, Mike M.!)

Want a loan? You might need my help

> Wordplay on **cosine** with **cosign**.

Comment: Yes. :-) Look up the word for "dry", not "wet". When you figure out that clue, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm new here. Are we allowed to help? I think I know what it is.

Comment: @MikeM. Welcome to Puzzling! Yes of course

Comment: @Xylius Thank you. TBH, I'm just new to participating. I joined a while ago.

Comment: @Josh I believe the OP is referring to _sec_. It means _dry_ in French, and secant - abbreviated _sec_ - is the reciprocal of cosine.

Comment: @MikeM. I see, my bad

Comment: @Xylius Not at all! I misspoke initially. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> cos, the mathematical (trigonometric) function that's the ratio of the adjacent side of a right triangle to its hypotenuse.

friendly with sin. In fact, we're practically twins

> You mean $\sin$, the ratio of the triangle's opposite to its hypotenuse. They're twins in the sense that $\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(x)$

I'm the opposite of dry, if you'll pardon my French

> Dry means "sec" in French, which is the multiplicative inverse of cos.

Want a loan? You might need my help

> I'm not sure about this one, but I'm guessing that has to do with how the money you have increases when you get a loan, but it's bound to decrease after some time when you pay it, similar to how the value of the cos function goes from 1 to 0 again with time.

Comment: Clever.  Unfortunately, this is basically the same as the other answer, which was posted 2½ hours before yours.  Also, the riddle says, “***I’m*** the opposite of dry”, but you’ve presented an argument why ***sin*** is the opposite of dry.

Comment: @PeregrineRook I couldn't care less about the time difference, as I came up with my answer independently before reading through that. But yes, sec is the inverse of cos, not sin. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: -1 because it's same as the other answer.

Comment: @manshu  Well, there's only one correct answer. And if 2 answers are correct, then they've got to be similar. Except that my answer failed to explain the 4th hint, and therefore it's different. I should also note that I managed to explain the 3rd hint before Josh (or Mike M) did, so your downvote can not be justified. Also, how do you expect one to know that his answer is similar to another if he's trying to solve the puzzle himself?

Comment: You say that you managed to explain the 3rd hint before him. But it was already explained in the comment section of that answer. And the more important thing is that you should check if you are duplicating any existing answer before posting another answer.

Comment: "It was already explained in the comment section" Nope, not even. Feel free to compare the time my first answer was posted to the time that comment was made.

Comment: @manshu that is completely unjustified. This answer is not the same. He made different explanations and different opinions.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Only the words differ. Not their meaning.

Comment: @AimanAl-Eryani Looks to me like Mike M. was 2 minutes faster.

Comment: @pydsigner It turned out it was actually 2 minutes and 2 seconds. But I'd still argue and say that 2 minutes is such a short time, and that the possibility I had started writing my answer and the comment was already there is very thin. But whatever floats your boat. You guys think too high of yourselves to even consider a possibility of error in your judgement. Let alone "stepping low" as in admitting and withdrawing a downvote. Either way, my answer will stay.

Comment: It's silly to argue among each other in comments over this. There are MANY questions where someone has the same answer as another person, and to me, that's fine. Sometimes people explain things in a way that the accepted answer didn't. I upvoted this answer because even though I answered first and was the accepted answer, Aiman WAS able to explain the one I couldn't. Now, let's stop arguing over this.